# fmax and fmin alternative in c89

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c99, c89

When trying to compile GLFW using visual studio 2010 I got error that 
"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fmax referenced in 
`Error  3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fmax referenced in function _star    F:\Dev\PROGS\GLFW\build\tests\cursor.obj    cursor`

But as I heard visual studio does not support c99 .Then what is workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, these functions were added in C99 and C++11. Microsoft's C compiler does not support C99, but later versions of the C++ compiler *do* support C++11. The one bundled with Visual Studio 2013 will have these functions. I'm not sure if they're usable when you're compiling C code or not.

If you're stuck on an older version of the compiler, like VS 2010, it's trivial to implement these functions yourself. Put them in an MSVC-compatibility header:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define INLINE __inline

    INLINE double fmax(double left, double right)
    { return (left > right) ? left : right; }

    INLINE double fmin(double left, double right)
    { return (left < right) ? left : right; }
#endif
```